# Counting points on a line or polygon using join: number of points are calculated incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, spatial-join, overlay

I am attempting to count the number of stream crossings within approx. 100m segments of a trail. I used this article to get quite close with join:

http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779

Unfortunately, this method fails to count a point once and awhile. For example, it counts 2 points on the line when in fact there are 3. I have tried creating a buffer on the points and the result is identical, so I don't think it is a proximity issue. I have also tried creating buffer on the line.

[image: There are three points!]

Comment: Based on your link and screenshot, I'm assuming you are using ArcGIS Desktop--please edit your question to clarify which version.  Could you also post a screenshot of the join you are performing?

Comment: Apparently too new to post more than two links. Joins and Relates => Joins. The result is the same whether I choose "intersects" or "closest"

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently I had some multi points that snuck in to my point layer. The explode tool cleaned those up and join was able to count the right number of points per segment.